# Is there a golang package that is equivalent to Python's ChainMap?

Tags: go

Python's ChainMap enables you to chain together several maps such that a lookup searches all of the maps in sequence until a matching key is found.  Here is one of many articles about it:

https://dzone.com/articles/python-201-what-is-a-chainmap

And the official documentation:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html

Does anyone know of any existing equivalent package written in Go?  I've so far been unable to find one, and would like to avoid re-inventing the wheel if one does exist.

Comment: Actually, no such a package in Golang SDK.

Comment: Okay, why the downvote?  Please leave a comment when downvoting so the original question can be improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found an implementation buried in the bigkevmcd/go-configparser package:  https://github.com/bigkevmcd/go-configparser/blob/master/chainmap/chainmap.go

The upside of this one is that it uses the original maps for storage, so does the right thing if one of them is updated later; this makes it work more like the original python version.  The downside is that the caller needs to call Get() and Len() functions rather than simply using the object as a normal map.

```
package chainmap

type Dict map[string]string

type ChainMap struct {
    maps []Dict
}

func New(dicts ...Dict) *ChainMap {
    chainMap := &ChainMap{
        maps: make([]Dict, 0),
    }

    for _, dict := range dicts {
        chainMap.maps = append(chainMap.maps, dict)
    }
    return chainMap
}

func (c *ChainMap) Len() int {
    return len(c.maps)
}

func (c *ChainMap) Get(key string) string {
    var value string

    for _, dict := range c.maps {
        if result, present := dict[key]; present {
            value = result
        }
    }
    return value
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's not package but it's fairly simple to implement something similar:

Let's do it with a `map[string]interface{}`

```golang
package main

import (
        "reflect"
        "testing"
)

type ChainMap struct {
        Map  map[string]interface{}
        maps []map[string]interface{}
}

func NewChainMap(maps ...map[string]interface{}) ChainMap {
        if len(maps) == 0 {
                return ChainMap{
                        Map:  make(map[string]interface{}, 0),
                        maps: maps,
                }
        }
        r := make(map[string]interface{}, len(maps[0]))
        for i := len(maps) - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
                m := maps[i]
                for k, v := range m {
                        r[k] = v
                }
        }
        return ChainMap{
                Map:  r,
                maps: maps,
        }
}

func (c ChainMap) Parents() ChainMap {
        if len(c.maps) < 2 {
                return c
        }
        return NewChainMap(c.maps[1:]...)
}
```

A small test:

```golang
func TestChainMap(t *testing.T) {
        var m = NewChainMap(
                map[string]interface{}{
                        "foo": "bar",
                },
                map[string]interface{}{
                        "foo":   "baz",
                        "hello": "world",
                },
                map[string]interface{}{
                        "foo": "baw",
                },
        )
        if !reflect.DeepEqual(
                m.Map,
                map[string]interface{}{
                        "foo":   "bar",
                        "hello": "world",
                },
        ) {
                t.Fail()
        }

        if !reflect.DeepEqual(
                m.Parents().Map,
                map[string]interface{}{
                        "foo":   "baz",
                        "hello": "world",
                },
        ) {
                t.Fail()
        }
}
```

Comment: How about the `parent` method?

Comment: I have adjusted my answer with the parents method. There's probably room for optimisation :)